# Replace contents in a column without using loop (R programming language)

Tags: r

Let's create a data frame `z`

```
x <- c(3,2,3,2,3,1,1,2)
y <- 1:8
z <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
```

Is it possible to replace 1, 2, 3 in column `x` with 'a', 'b', 'c'
without using loop?

Comment: `z$x[z$x == 1] <- 'a'` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'x' elements as numeric index for `letters[1:3]`

```
 z$x <- letters[1:3][z$x]
```

Or as @Mark suggested in the comments

```
 letters[z$x]
```

would be sufficient

Comment: It's easier than that - `z$x <- letters[z$x]`

Comment: @Mark Yes, that is more compact

Comment: out of curiosity, how do you perform this operation backwards?

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(z$x))` could be one way or `match(z$x, letters[1:3])`